# Ember.js: Access properties in "parent" controller when using {{render}} helper

Tags: ember.js

I have the following setup:

```
| // IndexController contains array of search result objects
| IndexController  (ArrayController) 
|     //Contains a search result object with row data (array) and search metadata
|---> ResultController (ObjectController) 
|          // Contains just the row data which is rendered into a sortable table 
|--------> TableController (ArrayController)
```

The `IndexController` retrieves a list of objects from the server when the user initiates a search.  Each object returned has some metadata about the search plus all the row data.

Each object is rendered using the `{{#each}}` helper in the Index template:

```
{{#each itemController="result"}}
    {{view App.ResultView}}
{{/each}}
```

The ResultView renders the metadata and then renders the actual table using the `{{render}}` helper like this:

```
<h2>{{pieceofMetaData}}</h2>
{{render "table" rows}}
```

Since I specified the model (in this case the row data), the `{{render}}` helper creates an instance of the TableController for each result object.  For example, if there are 3 result objects in the IndexController model then 3 TableControllers are created.  The TableController is an ArrayController to take advantage of the sorting that an ArrayController can do for me.  Inside the Table template I render the table itself:

```
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>   
          {{#each}}  <!-- Each row of data is rendered here -->
              <tr>
                  <td>{{firstName}}</td>
                  <td>{{lastName}}</td>
              </tr>
          {{/each}}
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

This works well but I have now run into an issue.  I need to be able to access properties in the `ResultController` from inside the `TableController`. Basically the `ResultController` contains information about which columns are sortable.  I cannot figure out how to access the parent `ResultController` from the child `TableController`.

I tried using `needs: ['result']` inside of the 'TableController' but this just instantiates a new instance of the `ResultController` rather than giving me access to the actual parent.

I created a working jsbin below that sets up the code I described here.

> http://emberjs.jsbin.com/paceqaki/7/edit

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Best,

Sarus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I would use a [PersonTableComponent](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/), check the [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/paceqaki/11/edit). Using the render helper is mostly used in a specific route context. I think, you are trying the get advantage of 'sortProperties', 'sortAscending' feature which is provided by Ember.SortableMixin, unfortunately this mixin seems only to work with ArrayProxy instances, so you would need to implement the sorting functionality in your component.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/person-table">  
    <h3>{{header}} )</h3>
     <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th {{action 'toggleSortFirstName' }}>First Name</th>
             <th {{action 'toggleSortLastName'}}>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>   
          {{#each sortedPeople}}
              <tr>
                  <td>{{firstName}}</td>
                  <td>{{lastName}}</td>
              </tr>
          {{/each}}
      </tbody>
   </table>
</script>



<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">  
    {{#each controller}}
        {{person-table header=header people=rows}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

App.PersonTableComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  sortProperty: 'lastName',
  sortAscending: true,


  sortedPeople: Em.computed(function(){

    // define your sorting functionality
    return this.get('people').sort( function(item) {
      return -1;
    });

  }).property('people.@each', 'sortProperty', 'sortAscending'),

  actions: {
    toggleSortFirstName: function() {


      var sortValue = !this.get('firstNameSortValue');

      // save current sort state
      this.set('fistNameSortValue', sortValue);
      this.setProperties({sortProperty: 'firstName',
                          sortAscending: sortValue});

    },
    toggleSortLastName: function() {

      var sortValue = !this.get('lastNameSortValue');

      // save current sort state
      this.set('lastNameSortValue', sortValue);
      this.setProperties({sortProperty: 'lastName',
                          sortAscending: sortValue});
    }
  }
});
```

Look at the EmberJS guide sections [Component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/) and [Rendering with helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/).

Comment: Thank you for your response!  My understanding was that components don't have controllers.  In this case I was using an ArrayController for the person-table so that I could take advantage of the sorting that you do using `sortProperties` and `sortAscending`.  Since I needed the controller I went with `{[render}}` over a component. Is it possible to the sorting functionality in a component?

Comment: Ah I see, the problem is that the parent controller is an ObjectController not an ArrayController.  The ObjectController has metadata on the search result in addition to the rows.  That's why I was using `{{render}}` to pass the rows to an ArrayController to take advantage of sorting on the table but needed the ObjectController to display the metadata on the table.  If I go the component route then I can't use the ArrayController.  Maybe I have to do that anyway and implement the sorting myself using an ArrayProxy or something?

Comment: If the component fires the "sorting action". I would create component actions which are managed in the component to sort a new sorted array. I will update the response to show what it could be.

Comment: This seems pretty good although just to clarify, with the way you're doing the sorting a new array is created everytime the sort order is updated or a person is added/removed from the array correct?  Is the best practice here to go the extra mile and use an ArrayProxy?

Comment: Actually it turns out you can use the new Ember.computed.sort and go the component route as you suggested!  Here's info on computed.sort http://balinterdi.com/2014/03/05/sorting-arrays-in-ember-dot-js-by-various-criteria.html.  Thank you for your assistance.